# How to highlight 2 selected divs from a list of divs

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an array of time Slots, I want to highlight the **start time and end time**.

WHAT I NEED IS: On my first click, Selected div will get highlighted, AND on my second click, another selected div will get highlighted.

My code for div formation in which Time is written is:

```
 <div *ngFor="let todayDate of dates">
   {{todayDate}}
   <div *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime">
     <div *ngIf="todayDate == time.date">
       <div class="timeSlots" (click)='timeSelector(time)'>
         {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes}}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <hr>
</div>
```

MY typeScript code is:

```
timeSelector(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(this.st.sh==-1 && this.st.sm==-1 && this.et.eh == -1 && this.et.em==-1){
        this.st.sh = event.hours;
        this.st.sm = event.minutes;
        console.log("Start time is ->"+this.st.sh + ":"+this.st.sm);
    }
    else if(this.st.sh!=-1&&this.st.sm!=-1&&this.et.eh ==-1 &&this.et.em==-1){
        this.et.eh = event.hours;
        this.et.em = event.minutes;
        console.log("End time is ->"+this.et.eh +":"+this.et.em);
    }
    else if(this.st.sh!=-1 && this.st.sm!=-1 && this.et.eh!=-1 &&this.et.em!=-1){
        this.st.sh = event.hours;
        this.st.sm = event.minutes;
        this.et.eh = -1;
        this.et.em = -1;
        console.log("Start Time is ->" + this.st.sh + ":"+this.st.sm);
        console.log("End time is not defined yet");
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you also show us the Typescript code of that component?

Comment: @Scorpioo590 Just a min

Comment: How is the `ScheduleTime` array defined?

Comment: ScheduleTime array contain 3 fields: date, hours and minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The "elegant" solution

If you are able to change the structure of `ScheduleTime` then you can add flags for activeStart-/EndTimes.

Your time-objects would then look something like this:

```
time {
  hours: 1,
  minutes: 1,
  date: new Date(),
  isStartDate: false,
  isEndDate: false
}
```

Now, when an element is selected you can just set the flags accordingly. In your template you could then format those times that have the flags set, e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime">
  <div *ngIf="todayDate == time.date">
    <div class="timeSlots" [ngClass]="{'startClass': time.isStartDate, 'endClass': time.isEndDate}" (click)='timeSelector(time)'>
      {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## Less elegant

You have your startDate and endDate in your component that is set correctly. In your template you can check for each item if it is identical to the start-/endDate and format accordingly.

This consumes more resources since everytime something changes all dates have to be parsed anew but will do the job if the `ScheduleTime` array is relatively small.

```
<div *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime">
  <div *ngIf="todayDate == time.date">
    <div class="timeSlots" [ngClass]="{'startClass': time.hour == st.sh && time.minutes == st.sm, 'endClass': time.hour == et.eh && time.hour == et.em}" (click)='timeSelector(time)'>
      {{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## A little piece of advise

Pleeeeaaassse do not call your variables `st`, `sh` etc.
I'm assuming this is short for `startTime`, `startHour` etc.

If so please name your variables accordingly. It might take up a little more space in your code but it makes it so much more readable! (If you are concerned about bundle size there are tools out there that could afterwards minify your variable names)

Comment: Thank you, Sir. U have helped me achieve the results and I will take care of declaring variable names from now on :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `timeSelector` function needs to store a reference to this latest selected time/element in a position where this loop can access it (good idea to pass an unique identifier for the loop, i.e. the index of the current loop could suffice here).

Once this is done, you can use a directive such as [ngClass](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ngclass) to see whether `clicked_index` (or whatever you save it as) equals the current index and then output the highlighting class if true.

Comment: I am getting your point, but would u please help me with the code example

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to grab the index of the time object you are getting from ScheduleTime and check if the index is the beginning or ending index. Based on that you can give separate class names with the "ngClass" functionality I showed below and therefore style the initial and ending divs differently.

```
<div *ngFor="let time of ScheduleTime; let i = index">
    <div *ngIf="todayDate == time.date">
        <div [ngClass]="i == 0 || i == ScheduleTime.length-1 ? 'timeSlots' : 'specialTimeSlots'" (click)='timeSelector(time)'>{{time.hours}}:{{time.minutes}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps